# import MySQLdb报错ImportError: cannot import name '_mysql' from 'MySQLdb' (D:\python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

win10
python3.7.3
Installed mysqlclient1.4.2

When I import mysqlclient, I get an error message when I run the code.
When I installed mysqlclient, I changed 'mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' to 'mysqlclient-1.4.2-py37-none-any.whl', because only then can I install it in windows. Mysqlclient
My English is not good, but I really hope to get help., thank you all.

```
C:\Users\22938>pip list

astroid           2.2.5
colorama          0.4.1
Django            2.2.1
isort             4.3.17
lazy-object-proxy 1.3.1
mccabe            0.6.1
mysqlclient       1.4.2
pip               19.1
pygame            1.9.6
pylint            2.3.1
PyMySQL           0.9.3
pytz              2019.1
setuptools        40.6.2
six               1.12.0
sqlparse          0.3.0
typed-ast         1.3.1
wrapt             1.11.1
```

---

```
>>> import MySQLdb
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb__init__.py", line 18, in 
>       from . import _mysql
>   ImportError: cannot import name '_mysql' from 'MySQLdb' (D:\python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb__init__.py)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install pymysql, I added the following code to the program.

```
>>> import pymysql
>>> pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> MySQLdb.__version__
'0.9.3'
```

Is this correct? Does it support python3?